# How to fetch images and videos from firebase server to my blog application?

Tags: java, android

[image]

I am developing an android blog application from firebase backend server...where I am fetching images successfully to my application in ViewPager layout.Now I want to fetch videos and images both from firebase storage...please help me to implements this method.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IFirebaseLoadDone {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    ViewPager viewPager;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseReference movies;
    IFirebaseLoadDone iFirebaseLoadDone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
       navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        Menu menu = navigation.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);



        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("MyNotifications","MyNotifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("general")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        String msg = "Welcome";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            msg = "failed";
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });




        movies = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Movies");


        iFirebaseLoadDone = this;
        loadMovie();

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true,new DeapthPageTransformer());

    }

    private void loadMovie()
    {

        movies.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            List<Movie>movieList = new ArrayList<>();
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                for(DataSnapshot movieSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    movieList.add(movieSnapShot.getValue(Movie.class));
                    iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(movieList);
                }
                Collections.reverse(movieList);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

                iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<Movie> movieList) {
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,movieList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoadFailed(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+ message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

---

### MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Movie> movieList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.movieList = movieList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {

        return view == o;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, container, false);
        final ImageView movie_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_image);
        final TextView movie_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        final TextView movie_description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_description);
        ImageView likeImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_like);
        ImageView sendImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_shr);
        Picasso.get().load(movieList.get(position).getImage()).into(movie_image);
        movie_title.setText(movieList.get(position).getName());
```

---

### activity_main.xml

```
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

### view_pager_item.xml

```
 <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:id="@+id/movie_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

---

### Movie.java

```
public class Movie
{
    private String name,description,image;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String name, String description, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i am fatching my profile image from firebase database:-

```
final ArrayList<Movie> yourList= new ArrayList<>();
     DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Movies");
     mDatabaseReference.child("0").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      pd.dismiss();
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Movie object = snapshot.getValue(Movie.class);
                            yourList.add(mobile);
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: how to get video and image both from the firebase server..??

Comment: I already fetching images from firebase but the concern is to fetch video and images both.

Comment: you can create a model class and set the variable names as you defined in firebase table. and i am changing my answer according to set values in model class

Comment: i have updated my answer please have a look. can you show me your movie class

Comment: appreciate the answer if it helps you

Comment: no update this :-  movies = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Movies").child("0"); now it will work

Comment: where video is stored in you database ?

Comment: I am uploading video in firebase storage and after that I copied the video url link and  put in the same image string

Comment: where I pasted image URL

Comment: are you able to get your url or not now ?

Comment: what is 0 here ?

Comment: appreciate the answer if i help you